# Blog / Share on Blogger Link

Tags: hyperlink, share, blogger, social-networking

Is there anyway to add share links to blogger like Facebook, GooglePlus, etc.? I thought there would be some kind of custom link for users to "Blog this" or something but I can't find anything like that after a lot of Googling.

I would think it'd be something like this:
[www.blogger.com/share?URL=x](http://www.blogger.com/share?URL=x)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Blogger has deprecated that feature i guess, but still accessable.

**Here is how.**

```
https://www.blogger.com/blog-this.g?u=http://blogname.blogspot.com/2014/03/watch-new-xmen-days-of-future-past.html&n=My%20Post%20Name&t=Hello%20This%20is%20my%20blg%20this%20page?
```

`?u=` for your blogpost URL.

`n=` for your blogpost Title.

`t=` for your blogpost content.

Now insert those Parameters automatically by using blogger data tags.

```
<a expr:href='&quot;https://www.blogger.com/blog-this.g?u=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;n=&quot; + data:post.title + &quot;&amp;t=&quot; + data:blog.metaDescription'>BLOG THIS</a>
```

Comment: I guess my question was worded poorly because this doesn't answer my question. I'm not using blogger. I want to add a Blogger button for people to "share/blog this" like they would if they wanted to share it on facebook or googleplus.

Comment: Cool. Thanks!. I tried to find some reminisce of that but didn't have any luck.